# VSCode - Can Find & Replace show dropdown of recent searches

Tags: visual-studio-code

This is one feature of Notepad++ that I am totally missing with vsCode - having memory of the last "n" things I searched for (and the last things I replaced them with).

Is there an extension that exists that enables this option?

Comment: you can navigate search recent history by up/down

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, I've just checked and I can navigate my recent FIND as well as REPLACE fields starting with the up arrow, provided that I am clicked onto either of those fields at first. It's well-hidden, but now that I know it's there I can adapt to it. Thanks again!